Vite storybook not respecting target config
I'm trying to create a storybook project with Vite. My dependencies require top-level await. I have the following main.ts file:
/// <reference types="vite/client" />

import type { StorybookConfig } from "@storybook/react-vite";
import { mergeConfig } from "vite";
import browserslistToEsbuild from "browserslist-to-esbuild";

const config: StorybookConfig = {
  stories: ["../../../packages/**/stories/*.stories.tsx"],
  addons: [
    "@storybook/addon-onboarding",
    "@storybook/addon-links",
    "@storybook/addon-essentials",
    "@chromatic-com/storybook",
    "@storybook/addon-interactions"
  ],
  core: {
    builder: "@storybook/builder-vite"
  },
  framework: {
    name: "@storybook/react-vite",
    options: {
      builder: {
        viteConfigPath: "../../vite.config.ts"
      }
    }
  },
  viteFinal: (config) => {
    return mergeConfig(config, {
      optimizeDeps: {
        exclude: ["*.html", "aws-sdk", "@ngrok", "fs"],
        include: ["universal-fs"]
      },
      build: {
        target: browserslistToEsbuild("defaults, not dead, > 0.5%, edge >= 120, chrome >= 108, Safari >= 15")
      }
    });
  }
};
export default config;

As you can see I am converting my browserlist to esbuild targets. The conversion is succesfull. However, when I run the storybook I get an error:
Top-level await is not available in the configured target environment ("chrome87", "edge88", "es2020", "firefox78", "safari14" + 2 overrides)

I have tried everything mentioned here as well as patching the problematic package with no luck. What can I do. I am using @storybook/builder-vite version 8.3.0.

Hey, did you ever get this resolved?
